# How can I use NTLM authentication in a DataSnap Server/Client Application?

Tags: delphi, datasnap, indy10

It looks like [Indy 10 Tiburon already has experimental NTLM support](http://www.delphipraxis.net/topic157784.html).

How can I activate the NTLM authentication for the DataSnap server/client applications and use the logon information (user name, password, domain) of the destination DataSnap Server?

Comment: Hello, did this resolve for you? 5 years later I'm at the same spot where you where. In my case I need the DataSnap server to work under the original caller account connecting to a COM+ server. Perhaps there have been some development in later releases.